# Can there exist two minimal dfa for same regular language?

Tags: automata, regular-languages, finite-automata

As said the answer is pretty simple "no", but that is not what i encountered. Here is the summary : i took a regular language , produced two ways of accepting same language (the ways in my understanding produce same language -please correct me if i am wrong ),then formed the minimal DFA for both of them,used equivalence method to show they are equal-by making table(i call it as like this but ,may be you say it something different you will know when you see the table). But contrary to this that for all language there exist a single minimal dfa.I found that both minimal dfa formed by my method can't be reduced to a single minimal dfa . which means for a language we could have 2 minimal dfa (here i found 2 , they could be more by this result)

I used two language , here in L1 i used "absolute function"  in"|n(a)- n(b) |" ,

L1 ={ |n(a) - n(b)|=3m ,m is set of integers(positive or negative-but be aware the it hardly makes any difference if "m" is negative ,as we have used "absolute function" on the  difference so "m" will always positive}. here "n(a)" is number of "a" in the string and similarly n(b). In simple words " L1 is the language generated by taking absolute difference of (n(a)-n(b)) and then checking that the length of string  is divisible by 3 or not ".

Now comes the second language L2 = {(n(a) - n(b))mod 3 = 0 }

below are my methods used please correct me where i am wrong.[image: here are my calculations]

Comment: The minimal DFA is unique. You can find a proof in many textbooks.

Comment: Your two DFAs have a different number of states. A DFA is minimal if it has the minimum number of states. So one of your DFAs isn't minimal.

Comment: Yeah but iam unable to minimise the dfa1 to dfa2 so there must be something wrong here, I request you to please look in to this

Comment: You must be applying the minimization algorithm incorrectly.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus thanks for you valuable suggestion , i found my mistake , so thanks , actually it was in the minimisation ,so iam taking this question down

Comment: @YuvalFilmus do you want me to take this down , as it does not make self justification  to answer your own quesiton

Comment: Let's leave this for the mods to decide.

Comment: We discourage "please check whether my answer is correct" questions, as only "yes/no" answers are possible, which won't help you or future visitors. See [here](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/questions/597/) and [here](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/questions/519/). Can you edit your post to ask about a specific conceptual issue you're uncertain about? As a rule of thumb, a good conceptual question should be useful even to someone who isn't looking at the problem you happen to be working on. If you just need someone to check your work, you might seek out a friend, classmate, or teacher.

Comment: Given that it's unlikely that this particular question will be of help for others in the future, I don't see any reason against deleting the question.

Comment: @Raphael the question is indeed have a great potential if you look from different point of view, my way of saying to turn down the question was that i have discovered my answers with little help from Yuval but it was the same question which was unanswered before me for almost 16-18hrs that is substantial proof of the potential of something. further you may be  in tip 1% but majority lies below , so from there prospective the question matters and i want to show honesty towards stackexchane points i earn that was the main reason for the takedown else the question is not easy to understand.

Answer (score 1):

After looking closely again to the minimization of the dfa1 you will found that dfa1 = dfa2 so both the language are equal.

during minimisation of dfa1 you will find that state 1=4 and 2=3 hence the final combination will be

$\pi$0 ={1,2,3,4} {0}  (0 length-(by length i mean length of string) equivalent)

$\pi$1 = {1,4} {2,4} {0}  (1 length equivalent )

$\pi$3 = {1,4} {2,4} {0} ( 2 length equivalence)

hence $\pi$2 =$\pi$3 means the dfa1 has been minimized. And when you make the tansition-table of minimized dfa1 its equal to dfa2.